# Declare model before create connection in ming

Tags: python, mongodb, ming

I want delcare my models before make connection with database (for some reason like multi-threading, and dynamic load of database config uri).

Documentation say to use like that:

```
from ming import create_datastore
from ming.odm import ThreadLocalODMSession
from ming import schema
from ming.odm import FieldProperty
from ming.odm.declarative import MappedClass

session = ThreadLocalODMSession(
    bind=create_datastore('odm_welcome')
)

class WikiPage(MappedClass):
    class __mongometa__:
        session = session
        name = 'wiki_page'

    _id = FieldProperty(schema.ObjectId)
    title = FieldProperty(schema.String(required=True))
    text = FieldProperty(schema.String(if_missing=''))
```

We can see what model declaration need `session` (in `__mongometa__`). How can i declare WikiPage model without `session` variable ? And set it later ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be declare model without `__mongometa__`:

```
class WikiPage(MappedClass):
    _id = FieldProperty(schema.ObjectId)
    title = FieldProperty(schema.String(required=True))
    text = FieldProperty(schema.String(if_missing=''))
```

Then make make mapping manually with a collection:

```
session = ODMSession(bind=create_datastore(uri))
collection_ = collection('wiki_page', session)
session.mapper(WikiPage, collection_)
```