# How do I pass the session object of a ThreadLocalODMSession to a class defined in another python file?

Tags: python-3.x, ming

I hope I can explain this issue correctly.

I want to define the `ThreadLocalODMSession` object in one python file, and have defined several other files with the classes that represent the mongo collection. But the sample source code for ming always shows the `ThreadLocalODMSession` object as a local variable, that sets the `session` variable in the `__mongometa__` subclass of the collection definition class.

In the example, the definition of `WikiPage` is in the same script as the definition of the `ThreadLocalODMSession` (called `session`) object, and get passed in the `__mongometa__` definition.

```
class WikiPage(MappedClass):
class __mongometa__:
    session = session
    name = 'wiki_page'
```

I want to be able to pass the `session` object into the `__init__` method of the `WikiPage`, and then have the `__mongometa__` subclass set its copy of `session` on creation.

Comment: I dont know why I could not find this before, but this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41823430/142798

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare model before create connection in ming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807329/declare-model-before-create-connection-in-ming)